# Android - receiving data via bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

i have little problem. I'm working on application which is control device by bluetooth and which is receving data from this device.After recive, data is present on real time graph. Sending and presenting is done but i have problem with read data.

Data look like that :

'<' Ch1 Ch2 seq crc '>'

Ch1,Ch2 - uint16

seq, crc - uint8

entirety have 8 bytes

After recive i need Ch1 or Ch2  "pack up" to integer and show on graph.

Commented fragment in code is my solution but at the moment i cant test that(i dont know if this is work) so i want to ask you if this is good way to do that? Maybe there is a better way do to do that?

Here is code :

```
class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothCommandService";
public static final int EXIT_CMD = -1;



private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
private final InputStream mmInStream;
private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
public static int data;

public static void shiftRight(byte[] list)
{
    if (list.length < 2) return;
    byte last = list[list.length - 1];
    for(int i = list.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        list[i] = list[i - 1];
    }
    list[0] = last;
}

public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {


    mmSocket = socket;

    InputStream tmpIn = null;
    OutputStream tmpOut = null;

    try {
        tmpIn =  mmSocket.getInputStream();
        tmpOut =  mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    mmInStream = tmpIn;
    mmOutStream = tmpOut;
}
public void run() {
    byte [] buffer = new byte[8];
    while (true) {
        try {

            /*
            buffer[0] = (byte) mmInStream.read();
            shiftRight(buffer);
            if((buffer[7]=='<')&(buffer[1]=='>')){
                data = ((int) buffer[1] << 8) | ((int) buffer[2] & 0xFF);
             */
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {

            Log.e(TAG, "connection lost", e);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

shiftRight()

```
 public static void shiftRight(byte[] list)
{
    if (list.length < 2) return;
    byte last = list[list.length - 1];
    for(int i = list.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        list[i] = list[i - 1];
    }
    list[0] = last;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why not send the data as objects and use the ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream class? http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html
This way you only need to serialize the classes that you are sending as objects.

Comment: Sending protocol wasn't my part in project so i don't have any debt on that. Unfortunately it must be like it's right now.